# Resizing data using cv2.imresize for neural network input

Tags: python, image, opencv, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have to **scale down data** to feed into a **neural network**.

I wanted to use [cv2.imresize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize), but there are multiple options with regard to how it interpolates the data to scale it down:

- INTER_NEAREST - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
- INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
- INTER_AREA - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free
  results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the
- INTER_NEAREST method.
- INTER_CUBIC - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
- INTER_LANCZOS4 - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood

Has anyone experimented with these, and if so what have you found? Note: I don't have enough time to try out learning with all varieties of interpolation.

Comment: then just use INTER_AREA that work well for downsampling and is quite fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For down sampling image data (I presume the data is an image since you're using OpenCV), you can just use area averaging to get good performance in terms of speed and quality (unless the downscaling factor is quite small, where blurring may happen).

Nearest neighbor will drop some cells at regular intervals but will be quite fast since no interpolation is actually performed. However some [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) is to be expected with most images.

If quality is your main concern, use [Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling) (slower than bicubic, but higher quality images, generally speaking).

Bicubic and bilinear are known to perform quite badly for downscaling images for factors less than 0.5.

Comment: Thanks! When you say averaging do you mean INTER_AREA?

Comment: @angela, yes exactly. If the answer helps, upvote/accept.

Comment: How does INTER_NEAREST behaves when I downscale an image? It creates the reduced version by calculating the average pixel values of the original ?